# How to find bootstrap of a particular section

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have copied a menu from a responsive HTML template, I pasted it to another template which is also responsive, but when the device is changed to mobile, the menu is not properly aligned.

I don't know how to extract the bootstrap of the menu only from its original template.

Here is the code:

```html
<section id="food-menu" class="content-area bg-home-food-menu">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="section-title text-center">
      <h2>Discover our menu</h2>
      <div class="clear">
```

Comment: Not sure if you have mentioned the whole piece of code as I can't see any issue with the code above

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari am not able to provide the bootsrap code coz its alot

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari i just want to know, how to get the code from bootstrap of a particular section

Comment: Can you be more detailed, you want code from which section of bootstrap?

Comment: can you give me ur mail id

Comment: Share yours, I will respond to that

Comment: zubairnazeroliyat@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the responsive styles for your code. Try adding the media queries for your Mobile view.That will fix the issue you are facing.